# for a given template type find its exact match or best suited type to convert it to, from the list of types available in the variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to implement a template, that will have the following definition

```
template<typename TypeToConvert, typename ... ListOfAvailableTypes>
struct best_match{...}
```

and will yield to a type that provides 2 members

```
1. value_type typedef - that is either exact match of TypeToConvert, if TypeToConvert was listed in ListOfAvailableTypes pack, or is the best suited type to convert TypeToConvert to, from the list of types available in ListOfAvailableTypes 
2. int index - that will contain the position of the found type in ListOfAvailableTypes pack
```

As a small example

```
 best_match<const char[4], std::string, int, void const*>
```

should yield to a type that provides below 2 members

```
best_match<const char[4], std::string, int, void const*>::value_type = void const*
best_match<const char[4], std::string, void const*>::index = 2
```

I could  implement this if I wanted to find exact match or convertible match, but how can I do this to find the best suited convertible type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You leverage overload resolution. There's probably a shorter implementation than this

```
template<size_t I, typename T>
struct tester
{
    static T type(T);
    static std::integral_constant<size_t, I> index(T);
};

template<typename...>
struct overloader;

template<size_t... Is, typename... Ts>
struct overloader<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...>
    : tester<Is, Ts>...
{
    using tester<Is, Ts>::type...;
    using tester<Is, Ts>::index...;
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct best_match
{
    using overloader = overloader<std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>, Ts...>;
    using value_type = decltype(overloader::type(std::declval<T>()));
    static constexpr auto index
        = decltype(overloader::index(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for a good implementation @Passer By, marking this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following C++20 approch.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template<typename TypeToConvert, typename... ListOfAvailableTypes>
struct best_match
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(ListOfAvailableTypes) > 0, "ListOfAvailableTypes must not be empty");

    static constexpr auto find_best_match() noexcept
    {
        constexpr auto update_best_match = [](auto best) constexpr noexcept {
            return [i = 0, &best](auto&& candidate) mutable constexpr -> decltype(auto) 
            {
                if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<decltype(candidate), TypeToConvert> &&
                    (!std::is_same_v<TypeToConvert, decltype(candidate)>) &&
                    (!std::is_same_v<decltype(best), void> || 
                        !std::is_convertible_v<decltype(candidate), void>)) 
                {
                    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<decltype(best), void> ||
                        std::is_convertible_v<decltype(candidate), decltype(best)>)
                    {
                        return decltype(candidate){std::forward<decltype(candidate)>(candidate), i};
                    }
                }
                return std::move(best);
            };
        };

        return std::apply([&](auto&&... args) constexpr noexcept 
            {
            return (update_best_match(void{})(
                decltype(args){std::forward<decltype(args)>(args), 0}), ...);
            }
        , std::tuple_cat(std::tuple<ListOfAvailableTypes...>{}, std::tuple<>{}));
    }

    using value_type = typename decltype(find_best_match())::value_type;
    static constexpr int index = decltype(find_best_match())::index;
};
```

Comment: This implementation doesn't seem to work. Can you please test this code using the example I provided above?